# Reading from txt causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, file

I'm reading from this text file called beatSheet.txt.

> A: 100
>   A: 101
>   A: 102
>   A: 103
>   A: 104
>   A: 105
>   A: 117
>   A: 120
>   A: 122
>   A: 126
>   A: 128
>   A: 129
>   A: 130
>   A: 131
>   A: 133
>   A: 138
>   A: 139
>   A: 140
>   A: 142
>   A: 149
>   A: 15
>   A: 151
>   A: 155
>   A: 156
>   A: 158
>   A: 16
>   A: 164
>   A: 166
>   A: 17
>   A: 172
>   A: 174
>   A: 18
>   A: 180
>   A: 182
>   A: 184
>   A: 188
>   A: 189
>   A: 19
>   A: 32
>   A: 36
>   A: 40
>   A: 45
>   A: 46
>   A: 55
>   A: 56
>   A: 57
>   A: 58
>   A: 63
>   A: 65
>   A: 68
>   A: 70
>   A: 72
>   A: 74
>   A: 79
>   A: 80
>   A: 81
>   A: 82
>   A: 86
>   A: 94
>   A: 95
>   A: 96
>   A: 97
>   A: 98
>   A: 99
>   ...(continues for letters s, k, and l)

When I call this method

```
public void openFile(String file) throws IOException{
    FileReader fileToRead = new FileReader("res/"+file);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fileToRead);

    int numLines = readLines(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < numLines;i++){
        if(bf.readLine().contains("A")){
            aList.add(Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine().substring(3)));
        }
        if(bf.readLine().contains("S")){
            sList.add(Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine().substring(3)));
        }
        if(bf.readLine().contains("K")){
            kList.add(Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine().substring(3)));
        }
        if(bf.readLine().contains("L")){
            lList.add(Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine().substring(3)));
        }
    }
    bf.close();
}
```

I get a NullPointerException. Can anyone explain why? This should work.

Comment: Did you step line by line with a debugger to find the offending code?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call **readLine()** it moves ahead in your file.

So on every loop you're actually **reading 4 to 8 lines** instead of 1. 
Once you run out of lines to read, readLine() returns null which causes the NullPointerException.

change your loop to:

```
while(true) {
    String str = bf.readLine();

    if(str == null) {
        break;
    }
    if(str.contains("A")){ 
        aList.add(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(3)));
    }
    ...
```

As to call readLine() only once per loop.

no need for `int numLines = readLines(file);` you'll know you're done when readLine() returns null.